# Jquery Scroll to certain position from a different page

Tags: jquery, ajax

The issue that I am facing is that I was a huge page with lots of links present in it . When the user clicks on the links he is directed ti different pages based on the link he clicks , and then he is directed back to the main page . I wanted to know , is it possible for the user to come back to the same place where he had clicked the link . Right now he is just taken to the top of the main page

Comment: you should be using page bokmarking for this

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="actionname#someThing"> </a>

<div id="someThing"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try out this plugin:

http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Answer (score 0):

if you add a # then it is possible like

```
<a href="home.php#testimonials"> </a>

<div id="testimonials"></div>
```